# QuickBlox VideoChat demo OnOpponentVideoDataReceived not called

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I have some trouble with the OnQBVideoChatListener in QuickBlox, the two methods `onOpponentVideoDataReceive` and `onOpponentAudioDataReceive` are never called. Here is how I implemented the cameraView and the opponentView. It's basically the same as the sample app given [here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat). I have tried to run the sample Video chat app on my phone and tablet however the same issue occures and only the cameraView gets updated. The opponent view is always black. Is there anyone who has experienced the same trouble and have a solution ?

Thanks a bunch !

```
private void initViews() {

    // Setup UI
    opponentView = (OpponentGlSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.opponentView);
    cameraView = (CameraView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);

    cameraView.setCameraFrameProcess(true);
    // Set VideoChat listener
    cameraView.setQBVideoChatListener(qbVideoChatListener);

    // Set Camera init callback
    cameraView.setFPS(6);

    cameraView.setOnCameraViewListener(new OnCameraViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraSupportedPreviewSizes(List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes) {
            Camera.Size firstFrameSize = supportedPreviewSizes.get(0);
            Camera.Size lastFrameSize = supportedPreviewSizes.get(supportedPreviewSizes.size() - 1);
            cameraView.setFrameSize(firstFrameSize.width > lastFrameSize.width ? lastFrameSize : firstFrameSize);
        }
    });

    // VideoChat settings
    videoChatConfig = (VideoChatConfig) GlobalVar.getObject(tag);

    try {
        QBVideoChatController.getInstance().setQBVideoChatListener((QBUser)GlobalVar.getObject(GlobalVar.CURRENT_USER_KEY), qbVideoChatListener);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


OnQBVideoChatListener qbVideoChatListener = new OnQBVideoChatListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
        if (videoChatConfig.getCallType() != CallType.VIDEO_AUDIO) {
            //... 
        }
        else{
            QBVideoChatController.getInstance().sendVideo(videoData);
            Log.i(tag,"videoData sent!");  // THIS IS EXECUTED
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMicrophoneDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        QBVideoChatController.getInstance().sendAudio(audioData);
        Log.i(tag,"AudioData sent!");  //SO IS THIS 
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpponentVideoDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
        Log.i(tag,"received img from opponent");   //NOT CALLED 
        opponentView.loadOpponentImage(videoData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpponentAudioDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        Log.i(tag,"received Audio from opponent");   //NOT CALLED
        QBVideoChatController.getInstance().playAudio(audioData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(boolean progress) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoChatStateChange(CallState callState, VideoChatConfig chat) {
        //... STUFF 
    }
};
```

Comment: @cyc115- I am facing the same issue right now. Did you found any solution ??

Comment: I did not solve the problem. My solution was to move away from QuickBlox and used OpenTok SDK instead. Give them a try!